# Full text search in SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, full-text-search

What minimal versions of SQL Server and Oracle are supported full text search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle Text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm) is capable for full text search, I suppose you can use it from 9.2 version upwards

Comment: It was available in 8i as "Oracle8i interMedia Text". Of course that is well out of support